# How turn on clipboard on Android emulator on virtual keyboard?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How turn on clipboard on Android emulator on virtual keyboard?

I've done this before but don't remember how I did it.

[image: clipboard on keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

1. Activate keyboard (press F12)
2. Click on the place you want to paste and long press (press until you
   see the word PASTE)
3. Done.